# System.ObjectDisposedException: Store must be open for this operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, openxml, isolatedstorage

there is an MVC4 application on IIS7 Windows2008 machine. the application runs as ApplicationPoolIdentity and the appropriate user has access to the ProgramData\IsolatedStorage folder.
it has also permission on the C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Local Settings\Application Data\IsolatedStorage folder as well.
but still receive exception while writing big excel files with openxml.

```
ERROR MHDB.MvcApplication - System.ObjectDisposedException: Store must be open for this operation.
at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.SafeIsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, ReliableIsolatedStorageFileFolder folder)
at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.CreateUserScopedIsolatedStorageFileStreamWithRandomName(Int32 retryCount, String& fileName)
at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.EnsureIsolatedStoreStream()
at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.SwitchModeIfNecessary()
at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressEmulationStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ProgressiveCrcCalculatingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.FlushBuffer()
at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.RawText(Char* pSrcBegin, Char* pSrcEnd)
at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteEndElement(String prefix, String localName, String ns)
at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteEndElement()
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlPartRootElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlPartRootElement.SaveToPart(OpenXmlPart openXmlPart)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.SavePartContents()
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Dispose()
at BL.OpenXML.Export(DataTable dt, Stream fs, Boolean createNewDocument)
at BL.BusinessLogic.CreateOpReport(UnitOfWork uow, String user, String orgapath, List`1 orgaids, Boolean isfin, String cycle, String startperiod, String endperiod)
at MHDB.Controllers.HomeController.GetFileAsStream()
at MHDB.Controllers.HomeController.ExportExcel()
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass13.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__10()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Due to the System.IO.Packaging when you write files larger than 10MB internally it will no longer hold the data temporarily in memory until next save but will switch over to Isolated Storage. That on its own can cause a lot of problems because IsolateStorage is not meant to be used with multiple thread/multiple instances of the same application and you could be facing some permission issues with this as well.

Considering that this is a web app I think it may relate to multiple user writing at same time but all being resolved to the same Isolated Storage location..

I have stumbled upon this problem with multiple instances of same app all being resolved to same location. I am still looking for an elegant solution but I was able to force each instance to be resolved to a different IsolatedStorage location and be unique by using this:

```
var rootDirUserField= typeof(IsolatedStorageFile).GetField("s_RootDirUser", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
rootDirUserField.SetValue(null, "<unique location in isolated storage>");
```

This works because the static field IsolatedStorageFile.s_RootDirUser is used in resolving a new directory to use. My fix was specific to the User | Domain | Assembly scope.

I am keen to get a better solution to fix this problem.

Comment: Please see the answers I got for this problem. I hope my problem is the same as yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922941/store-must-be-open-for-this-operation-system-io-packaging-package?noredirect=1#comment59504725_35922941

Comment: Hi. thanks for this another link. i think i'll go for building my own open xml sdk with the new Packaging namespace